# Flex and Bison Parser, same character for two tokens

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm doing a small parser with Bison and Flex to learn.

I have a problem, I want to be able to have the binary OR operator as

`exp || exp`

where the character '|' two times signifies the OR operation of the two expressions one to the left and one to the right.

But I want to also be able to define absolute value as

`| exp |`

where the character '|' is used like parentheses to signify absolute value of the expression within.

Now I'm running into trouble with the parser not being able to correctly parse strings such as

`||exp| + exp|`

which I want to be parsed as

`(| (|exp|) + (exp) |)`

meaning the absolute value of the absolute value of an expression added with another expression.

Here my parser then reads the first two pipe characters as an OR and then discovers an error with the rest, which makes sense but is not what I want.

I have tried giving different precedence to rules in my bison file, and tried making flex not recognizing the double pipe but only recognizing one pipe at a time, but I'm not as versed in either to be 100% sure of the impact of what I'm doing.

The only solution I have found so far is forcing space characters on both sides of the OR operator which works but is not pretty. I could also just use another character for one of the operations but I want to be stubborn atleast a little while and I thought there was something to learn here.

thanks for reading my problem, I hope someone has an idea for a solution

cheers

Comment: Your example is unambiguous. But which interpretation of `|a|||b|||c|` do you choose? `|(a || (|b|) || c)|`? Or `(|a|) || b || (|c|)`? And what is the basis for your choice?

Comment: Damn, I had not thought of that, great question rici. In this case I think I would choose `(|a|) || b || (|b|)` my reasoning being I think it makes more sense to ask for the OR operation on numbers than it does to take the size of Boolean values.

Comment: That choice will be hard to express syntactically, I think.

Comment: I think I'll just end up changing the characters for absolute value, but thanks